# Alfresco SMTPAddressFailedException 553 error

Tags: tomcat, alfresco, alfresco-share, catalina.out

So we are using Alfresco Community Edition 5.2, and this error only occurs when starting a workflow. Supposedly, after starting a workflow, the assigned user would be notified via email. But instead, the error below occurs:

```
2020-06-19 13:24:28,223  ERROR [action.executer.MailActionExecuter] [mailAsyncAction7] Failed to send email to [user] : org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses; nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 553 5.7.1 <user@company.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user username; message exceptions (1) are:
    Failed message 1: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses; nested exception is:
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 553 5.7.1 <user@company.com>: Sender address rejected: not owned by user username
```

alfresco-global.properties settings:

```
mail.host=company.domain.com
mail.port=25
mail.protocol=smtp
mail.encoding=UTF-8
mail.smtp.auth=true
mail.username=username
mail.password=password
mail.from.default=alfresco@company.com
```

I'm sure I used the correct username and password for the SMTP authentication. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please verify that your **mail.host**, **mail.username** and **mail.password** are the good ones ?
Next, you can verify the **recipient's mail adress**.

I think one of these information causes your issue.

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

It might also be helpful to install a test smtp server which will allow to verify the validity of your mail server. FAKESMPT 2.0 is one product people use with Alfresco, by default windows uses port 25 and linux platforms use port 2525.

It can be found here:

http://nilhcem.com/FakeSMTP/ Once you have verified that your mail server is running sending and receiving emails, update your alfresco-global.properties accordingly.